# NanoVNA measurements of attenuation do not match simulation results

Tags: rf, ltspice, vna

[image]I am measuring RF Tap in Pi configuration using NanoVNA (see attached picture for test setup).

If I terminate RF Path output with 50ohm resistor and measure attenuation between RF Path input and RF Tap output I get expected -40dB. When I leave RF Path output open I get -34dB. (see picture for measurement setup).

I can get such results in LTSpice only if I do not explicitely account for NanoVna Channel 1 input impedance, which I believe shall be 50ohm (scenario 1).

If I add 50ohm NanoVna channel 1 input impedance I get RFTap attenuation of either -40dB or -46dB... (-46dB I cannot measure with Nano)

Do you have any idea where the issue might be? Can it be that NanoVNA input impedance of Channel 1 is set to high value when in logmag mode?[image]

Comment: “Can it be that NanoVNA input impedance of Channel 1 is set to high value when in logmag mode?” I dunno. Put it in logmag mode and use a multimeter to measure the input resistance?

Answer (score 0):

Based on great hint from Fesz who runs Fesz Electronics youtube channel, to align spice simulation results with measurements done with nanovna one need to take into account corretion nanovna calculates during calibration process.
Basically when nanovna is "through" calibrated in situation when impact from cabling can be neglected such correction is +6dB i.e. to each simulation result this value has to be added.
The correction value can be calculated knowning that input impedance of both channels is 50ohm, this means that input voltage shall be devided by 2 to arrive at voltage level which is supplied to channel 1 of the device.

So in my case for unterminated RF Path simulation was showing attenuation of -40dB, which gives -40dB + 6dB = -34dB, the same for terminated RF Path with 50ohm load, in such case simulation result was -46dB, which gives -46 + 6 =40dB. Both results are perfectly aligned with actual measurements. Thanks Fesz!